# Xamarin Forms Read and Write external storage issue on API33

Tags: android, .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Xamarin Forms application that used to target Android 12. All I did was simply change to target Android 13 (API33) and when I did that, I can no longer use READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE or WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE. I am using Xamarin.Essentials to handle the permissions, that hasn't changed either.

Again, I changed no code, just changed the target to Android 13. So, of course those permissions are in my manifest.

I did update Xamarin.Essentials to the latest version, 1.8.1 and that didn't help. It still comes up "Denied" every time and doesn't even pop up the dialog for the user to allow when I call to request the permission.

I have seen the article like this one which also links to the Android Developer page: [StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com)

So, it seems this was changed on purpose on Android 13 and I must use those specific folder/permissions in the article. Those are only Images, Videos or Audio.

My question is simple, many apps like mine, might need to create documents and write log files both of which, I want the user to be able to browse to both by using the File Browser on the device and/or when plugging the device into USB on their computer and browsing. These files are only created and read from my app, in fact, I used to create a sub folder for my app in the external storage. So, with these new changes, how can I still achieve this? It seems clumsy to store my documents and log files in Images or Videos and I can't store them in application storage because that folder isn't browsable by the user.

UPDATE: Several responses I have received seem to think you can still write to the "public external" folder and maybe without "WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" permission even though this goes against everything I have read about SDK 33, I went ahead and tried both ways.

First, I tried requesting the "WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" permission but as suspected and pointed out by many, you cannot request this permission anymore in SDK33. Android doesn't even try, doesn't prompt the user to accept the permission and just immediately returns with "Denied". So, this is not an option, period.

Second, I tried seeing if I could write to external storage even without the permission (since you can't get it anyway). Also, as I have read, you cannot. You get an "Access Denied" error just simply trying to create a sub directory in external storage. Here is a screenshot of the snippet I tested with and the exception. So, unless I am not doing this correctly, this will not work either.

[image: Exception Creating Folder]

Comment: It is pretty unclear what you call 'new changes'. And of course you can still make folders on external storage if you know where exactly.

Comment: `Those are only Images, Videos or Audio.` Why dont you name them? And they are only for reading. Never for creating/writing. So have nothing to do with your problem.

Comment: `I can't store them in application storage ` Again why dont you name it. And as there are at least two private storage locations ...

Comment: The issues you're encountering are due to changes in how Android handles file permissions, particularly with the introduction of Scoped Storage in Android 10 (API 29) and further restrictions in Android 11 (API 30) and Android 13 (API 33). Scoped Storage limits access to broad file system paths and instead encourages apps to use app-specific directories or access files through the system file picker.

Comment: @GuangyuBai-MSFT So, I think this is going to be my solution. For example, with log files that I might want to user to have access to, I will just store them in scoped storage and add a mechanism where the user can click a button in my app to save the log somewhere where they can access it. I will then invoke the system file picker and let them save the log from scoped storage over to where they choose in the picker, at which point they can access it. Sound right?

Comment: @blackapps I don't know if I understand what you are saying. Here is my question, we will use log files as an example, which I save as a text file. Sometimes, the user wants to gain access to this text file. If I store it in scoped storage, that will work for my app but the user cannot gain access to that file. It is a text file so it doesn't really make sense to be in Images, Videos or Audio. I think the best solution is to use the file picker from my app and let the user save it where they want (ie: move it from scoped to somewhere where they can access it).

Comment: It is nonsense to say that you save files in scoped storage.

Comment: `And of course you can still make folders on external storage if you know where exactly.` Pretty strange that you do not react to the point at my first comment. You are not even asking where.

Comment: `to be in Images, Videos or Audio.` Indeed and not even possible for .txt files.

Comment: @blackapps I really appreciate the help. You really sound snippy or annoyed and I hope that isn't the case, we are just all here to help and learn. Anyway, here is what I am not understanding by your comment, even if I use the public directory on external storage, don't I still need the "WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" permission granted? The name of the permission certainly implies that I do need it. On Android 13/SDK 33, you CANNOT gain access to that permission. It will be denied automatically, everytime as is documented in many other posts and the Android docs. So how can I write?

Comment: `even if I use the public directory on external storage, don't I still need the "WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" permission` I blame you for not having tried without.

Comment: @blackapps I don't know why you assume I didn't try it, no need to blame. Anyway, I just tried again to make sure I wasn't missing something, it DOES NOT WORK. I got an exception just simply trying to create a directory that "Access is Denied". I will edit my original post above so I can show a screenshot with the snippet that I was using and the exception. Either I am not understanding you and I am doing it wrong, in which case I would ask you kindly tell me what I am doing wrong in my screenshot or you are sadly mistaken that this is possible. Thanks!

Comment: No screenshots or pictures of code. Post complete reproducible code in a code block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your own folder in public directory Documents on external storage.

You can then save as many files in that folder as you want.

And you can use -what you call- the file picker to let the user pick files from it.

On Android 13+ devices you will not at runtime ask for storage read/write permissions. Instead your app by default has write permission in all public directories on external storage.

Comment: Marking as the answer. The missing step in this was that the root folder (ie: Documents, etc...) has to already be existing. You cannot create a folder in the root. However, if the folder exists, you can then create sub folders and/or write files to it with no issue and no permissions. Thank you @blackapps for pointing me in the right direction! I also tested writing to the "Android" folder since it is an existing folder and that worked too!